# call dll objects in java application

Tags: java, c#, jna

i have a c# dll file which contains a specific class that i need to use in some java application.

this is how i use it in my c# program:

```
using Lemmatizer; // this comes from my dll

private void Test(string inputText) {
    output = (new StemmingTools()).LemmatizeText(inputText, LevelOfLemmatizer.First, false);
    // StemmingTools class placed in the dll
}
```

how can i use the LemmatizeText function in my java program ?

i already used the jna library but it fails with instantiate the StemmingTools object from the dll.

Comment: JNA is for native code, but a C# dll contains MSIL. There is no easy way to do what you want, so I'd suggest re-writing the function in Java, or finding a library that does something similar.

Comment: @JornVernee unfortunately can't do that. it's an black box dll :(

Comment: Is the the .NET assembly COM-enabled? If so, you might be able to use the  interfaces via JNA's COM functionality

Comment: You can try to decompile the dll with tools like ILSpy or JustDecompile (both are free).

Comment: Check out jni4net: [Fast, object oriented, intraprocess bridge between JVM and CLR](https://github.com/jni4net/jni4net)